# I want to convert JSON data to a generic type in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, generics

Hello everyone I'm new to Flutter.
I want to convert JSON data to a generic type in Flutter.

```
class ServiceResult<T>
{
  T result;
  String message;
  bool hasError;
  bool hasSuccessMessage;
}
```

I can use
*Map<string, dynamic>*
But I don't want to use it dynamically. I want to cast to T.
I have always seen dynamic uses in my research. Is there a method that I can cast directly to T?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really avoid using Map<string, dynamic>.
Because that's the only way you map a JSON into a class object, but if you prefer to Convert a JSON into a T class here is the example.
first, create ServiceResult as you do
Then create T class for the result

```
class ServiceResult
{
  T result;
  String message;
  bool hasError;
  bool hasSuccessMessage;
}
class T{
  String yourStringHere;
  String yourAnotherStringHere;
  int yourIntHere;
}
```

crucial part

```
ServiceResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    message= json['message'];
    hasError= json['has_error'];
    hasSuccessMessage= json['has_success_message'];
    result = json['result'] != null ? new result .fromJson(json['result']) : null;
}
T.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    yourStringHere= json['your_string_here'];
    yourAnotherStringHere= json['your_another_string_here'];
    yourIntHere= json['your_int_here'];
}
```

bonus: Javier Lecuona create genius tools to convert a JSON into a class object, so you can be lazy like I do :P
here: https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that won't work for me. Because T can be anything to me. Example: UserDto, this class is defined. result = json['result'] as T not working.       
 I get this error.
 type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'UserDto' in type cast

Comment: How do I access fromJson if the incoming class is in a list in such a situation? or Dictionary?

Comment: your welcome ! oh wow, now I really understand your question. I think you can add a more advanced JSON parser class to do that, but I wouldn't recommend it. why would Rest API return something that isn't consistent?

Comment: Actually I know the types that will come but I still want to be able to afford them all. I was very surprised that this was so difficult in Dart language -.-"

Comment: indeed, sometimes flutter is too strict. but if you concern about your security I think it's a good point :D, I hope other folks will point light to you for your goal. but from me, I would recommend you too strict for everything :D and make your API more consistent so you don't have to worry about the unexpected error.